# Nullability annotation warnings after NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c-nullability

I was working on adding some nullability annotation to part of a header file, and I wanted the block to assume non-null, but pretty much every method afterwards was giving warning saying that I needed to add nullability annotations.

Example code for this below:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
- (void)testMethodWithParameter:(NSString *)par otherParameter:(NSString *)otherPar;
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

- (void)methodThatShouldntNeedAnnotationWithText:(NSString *)txt;
//Warning: Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)
```

Am I understanding these Macros incorrectly?  I thought it would contain the part that was said to be audited within the BEGIN/END block, but everything outside would still be `_Null_unspecified`

Is this working as intended, or is there something I have to do to make this work the way I thought?

Comment: I don't know if it is intentional or not, but I observed that as well. As soon as you have *any* nullability annotation in the interface file, you have to define nullability  *everywhere* in that file.

Comment: At least from my impression of how this works, it seems like `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` doesn't do anything within an interface.  The Apple Swift blog's example code shows the `BEGIN` before the `@interface` and the `END` after `@end` (for the interface).  Maybe it isn't meant to be used WITHIN a the interface for just part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` makes any parameter to be assumed as a non null variable, therefore:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
- (void)testMethodWithParameter:(NSString *)par otherParameter:(NSString *)otherPar;
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

is converted to:

```
- (void)testMethodWithParameter:(nonnull NSString *)par otherParameter:(nonnull NSString *)otherPar;
```

So, the absence of `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` doesn't mean that every parameter is assumed to be `nullable` nor `unspecified`, you still have to define it. So, for the other method you have to specify what you want, if you want the text could be `nullable` then add the keyword to the parameter like this:

```
- (void)methodThatShouldntNeedAnnotationWithText:(nullable NSString *)txt;
```

Comment: And, for `testMethodWithParameter` that is what I want, but why am I getting warnings about `methodThatShouldntNeedAnnotationWithText` after the `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` macro?

Comment: What I meant, you have to specify the `nullability` on your parameters, you can achieve this by using a `MACRO` or by specifying it on every parameter.

Comment: The `MACRO` is only affecting the method signatures between the `..._BEGIN` and `..._END`, so that's what the compiler is telling you, `methodThatShouldnt...` is missing the `nullability specifiers`

Comment: Ah, is there any way to tell the compiler to assume that the rest of the header is unaudited?

Comment: I think that's not possible (not sure tho), if you check the `NSObjCRuntime.h` (by cmd+clicking on `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`) you can see the definition of that macro alone, I can't see anything like that to let the methods unaudited

Comment: Yeah, I looked in there, hoping for `NS_ASSUME_NULL_UNSPECIFIED_BEGIN`, but it was not there.  I can audit it, but didn't want to do the whole thing quite yet.